# Image Upload - Can't move to the desired folder

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

it's my first time posting.

I doing a project site that needs to have a vote page where the user can upload a picture to be voted .

So far my code is

```
  <div class="container" align="center">
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 info">
           <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" required/>
          <br>
           <input type="text" name="uStyle" id="uStyle"  size="16" maxlength="32" placeholder="Style" required/><br>
           <input type="text" name="uOrigin" id="uOrigin" size="16" maxlength="32" placeholder="Origin" required/><br>
          <br>
          <br>
           <input type="submit" name="submitUp" value="submit"/>
           <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear It"/>
         </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

And on upload.php :

```
 $file_name =$_FILES['pic']['name'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['pic']['type'];

  $uploads_dir = "/img/vote/".$_FILES['file']['name'];

  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$uploads_dir);

  $target_file = $uploads_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

As for my destionation I am using xampp and i want to move the uploaded file to /xampp\htdocs\MAHSITE\img\vote

The code is located on "MAHSITE" . 
The Problem is that the uploaded pic won't go to the desired folder.The folder is writable.

Comment: *"and i want to move the uploaded file to /xampp\htdocs\MAHSITE\img\vote"* - So use that ;-) and not `/img/vote/` and make sure the folder can be written to. Or `/MAHSITE/img/vote/`.

Comment: tried it. doesn't work. also the whole project will be sent to prof. and i need him to be able to use it

Comment: In general you should _not_ use client provided data for internal processes. Here the specified filename as internal file system name. Use generic names instead (ID and timstamp based) and hold the client specified names in a database (if required).

Comment: About the issue: you claim "won't go to the desired folder"... That indicates that it either goes somewhere else or that it fails. If it fails then you have an entry in your http servers error log file. What does it say?

Comment: `$uploads_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])` that's wrong, you didn't use the right array name and the same for `$uploads_dir = "/img/vote/".$_FILES['file']['name'];`. @JohnKoufos why did you delete the question? I posted an answer below. Can you undelete it?

Comment: Oh thanks ,I am totaly blind ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$uploads_dir = "/img/vote/".$_FILES['file']['name'];`

You are using the wrong array name here, being `file`, it should be `pic`.

You also wanted to use `MAHSITE` as the base folder, so you need to include it in the path for it.

I.e.: `"/xampp/htdocs/MAHSITE/img/vote/"` instead of `"/img/vote/"`

You also used the wrong array name in

```
 $target_file = $uploads_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ should be "pic"
```

Using PHP's error reporting would have helped you during development:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Yeah , you are right. I am really sorry for the post . Rest is needed

Comment: @JohnKoufos ah no worries. I thought that you may have wanted to close the question properly.

Comment: You mean delete the post ? (first time using stackoverflow, dont know how these things work here)

Comment: Accepted the anwser and thanks once more , have a good day ( or night) .

Comment: @JohnKoufos You're most welcome. I made an edit to my answer. Look near the bottom about "Error reporting". Thanks and have a good day/evening as well, *cheers*